# mysql-slow.log analysis with goaccess Nothing valid to process

Tags: mysql, logging, goaccess

To visually analyze mysql-slow.log, I ran `goaccess -f mysql-slow.log` in my terminal and got this error:

> Nothing valid to process. Verify your date/time/log format.

My mysql-slow.log looks like this:

```
# User@Host: towfiqpiash[towfiqpiash] @ ip-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.ec2.internal [xx.xx.xxx.xxx]  Id: 396
# Query_time: 0.000180  Lock_time: 0.000056 Rows_sent: 38  Rows_examined: 39
SET timestamp=1482221404;
SELECT AQ.answer_id FROM `answer_quality_log` as AQ WHERE AQ.active=1;
```

I need appropriate `date-format`, `time-format` and `log-format` for goaccess configuration. Any help appreciated.

Comment: You can't parse MySQL logs. GoAccess is a web log analyzer.

Comment: Ohh. my bad :( Thanks for letting me know